# Android Button default state

Tags: android, button, background, state

Why is Button's default behaviour state_activated="false"?

Using this selector it never reaches the last row, it stays on the second line:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Let's say this selector is shared amongst Buttons and some layouts which pose as a button, but in layout's case, `setActivated(false)` is needed to change the background.

Comment: I can't think of a case where a Button would be `activated`. Perhaps you could list the different cases the button needs to have a different visual appearance, and we could go from there.

Comment: I have a layout that poses as a button, and at a certain point it becomes "inactive" but still clickable and enabled in order to appear disabled and to show a warning message when clicked on. Click action won't be registered when the layout's click option is disabled, so I had to use setActivated(). On some other layouts, some buttons also use the same selector, but they only have to respond to state_pressed, like a normal button would, yet they react on the state_activated. Thanks to you, now I know why, but still don't know how to fix/bypass it without using an another selector.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "'inactive' but still clickable". You could use `setEnabled(false)` as this is a method on the View, not on Button. The default behaviour of a disabled Button is to disable the click (i.e. no pressed state).

Comment: Same issue here. How did you solve the problem in the end? @rexxar

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I resorted to handling actions on the button (real button instead of a layout) programatically instead of through a selector after I figured out that this was a wrong approach to my problem. If I remember, I will write it here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default state of `activated` is false for all Views. The easiest way to understand why is to consider the case of tabs over a ViewPager.

The `activated` tab is the one which represents the visible page - it doesn't make sense for multiple tabs to be activated at the same time.

I mentioned in my [blog post](http://ataulm.com/android-view-states/) that `activated` could be described as "selected" to someone that didn't know the terms Android used.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this was helpful, now I fully understand what's the difference between those two states. 
Still, I can't figure out what put in the selector that can fix my problem. 
I think I'm going to have to add a second selector because both view's default state values are equal but initial reactions are different.
(I was the one commenting on your blog [in case that that didn't bring you here].)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add colors for activated and enabled states.
Like this :

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/some_color" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/some_color" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent"/>
```

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is still here, layout and button react differently because of their initial states